# VBA Object Variable Not Set - HTML Scraping

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape google, and am having trouble pulling multiple elements from HTML Segments. Google presents each search result as a "card" class. I keep getting the Object Variable Not Set error when I run the following code.

```
> Option Explicit
> 
> Sub StatusLetter()
>     SearchandScrape ("Apple") End Sub
> 
> Sub SearchandScrape(URL As String)
>     Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
>     Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
>     Dim HTMLCard As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
>     Dim HTMLCards As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
>     Dim Temp As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
>     Dim scrapedCard As New card
>     
>     IE.Visible = True
>     IE.navigate "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & URL & "&tbm=nws&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:d&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf_LHL1bngAhXqQ98KHTs2D4QQpwUIHw&biw=1282&bih=893&dpr=1"
>         
>     Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
>     Loop
>     
>     Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
>     
>     Set HTMLCards = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("card")
>     
>     For Each HTMLCard In HTMLCards
>         Temp = HTMLCard.getElementsByTagName("h3")(0)
>         Debug.Print Temp.innerText
>     Next End Sub
```

I get the Error in the for each loop. I want to be able to pull the text of 3 tags that is stored in a HTML segment. 2 of them are spans and the third is the h3 for each card in HTMLCards. Any recommendations on a fix for this. I cant seem to figure out how to correctly access these objects. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a proper wait for page load. Remember to quit the application after. There is only one element with that class name on the page. I think you actually want a different selector as shown below.

```
Option Explicit    
Public Sub StatusLetter()
    SearchandScrape "Apple"
End Sub

Public Sub SearchandScrape(URL As String)
    Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, headlines As Object, i As Long
    Dim agenciesAndTime As Object, agencies As Object, times As Object, descriptions As Object
    Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & URL & "&tbm=nws&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:d&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf_LHL1bngAhXqQ98KHTs2D4QQpwUIHw&biw=1282&bih=893&dpr=1"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set headlines = .document.querySelectorAll("h3.r")
        Set agenciesAndTime = .document.querySelectorAll("h3.r + div span")
        Set agencies = .document.querySelectorAll("h3.r + div span:nth-of-type(1)")
        Set times = .document.querySelectorAll("h3.r + div span:nth-of-type(3)")
        Set descriptions = .document.querySelectorAll("#ires div.st")
        Dim results(), headers()
        headers = Array("Headline", "Agency&Time", "Agency", "Time", "Description")
        ReDim results(1 To headlines.Length, 1 To 5)

        If headlines.Length > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To headlines.Length - 1
                results(i + 1, 1) = headlines.item(i).innerText
                results(i + 1, 2) = agenciesAndTime.item(i).innerText
                results(i + 1, 3) = agencies.item(i).innerText
                results(i + 1, 4) = times.item(i).innerText
                results(i + 1, 5) = descriptions.item(i).innerText
            Next
        End If
        .Quit
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            .Cells.ClearContents
            .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
            .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How would I obtain the news organizations name and the time at which it was posted and the summary from the google card (the green text and the "7 hrs ago"). I'll eventually need to put it into rows. I can't get all of the information from .getElements... because it won't match up 1 to 1 as some cards will group related headlines and omit summaries.